# How to add List element to map by key?

Tags: java, arrays, list, hashmap, treemap

I use the following approach for sorting items by key:

```
final Map<Integer, UUID> map = new TreeMap<>();


while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

  // Add Items to the TreeMap
  mapppp.put(1, UUID.fromString("610e9040-840c-48c5-aa64-f193ed896133"));
  mapppp.put(2, UUID.fromString("4ff0055d-49a9-4e93-b960-ff70ae1007ce"));
  mapppp.put(3, UUID.fromString("751c79ce-445c-406a-9787-a754857a259c"));
  mapppp.put(3, UUID.fromString("dc721d77-509d-4bd3-8004-43a8daab5840"));  
  mapppp.put(3, UUID.fromString("4ca16aff-5a30-4638-8b38-3a93eddb0fc5"));  
  mapppp.put(3, UUID.fromString("e4be360b-cccb-42a2-b416-eb4bb623b49f"));            
}
```

However, I cannot add another element for the repeated key value (for example 3) and I think I should implement something like `Map<Integer, List<UUID>> map = new TreeMap<>();` rather than `Map<Integer, UUID> map = new TreeMap<>();`. However, I could not find a proper solution for that. So, how can I manage the repeated key values to be added to the map?

Comment: You might want to look at the `MultiMap` collections in Guava: https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 2):

You could indeed use a `Map<Integer, List<UUID>>` as you suggested. You can then use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to create an empty map if the key isn't there, and add the value to the key:

```java
final Map<Integer, List<UUID>> map = new TreeMap<>();

addToMap(int key, String value) {
    mapppp.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried something like this but it throws "*Cannot infer arguments*" error in the `ArrayList`

Comment: @Robert added the definition of the map. If that isn't the issue, could you share the code you have and the error?

Comment: The problem is related to method. I updated it as `map.computeIfAbsent(key, value -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);` and it fixed one of two problem. But there is still "*Variable 'value' is already defined in the scope*" error pointing the "value" in `.. value ->  ...` part. Any idea?

Comment: **BUT**, if I use like `map.computeIfAbsent(key, value1 -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);`, it seems to working, but `value1` is here pointless and I cannot make it work using empty parameter e.g. passing `()` instead of `value1`. Any idea about my last 2 comments?

Comment: @Robert my bad, didn't notice I was reusing `key` - edited and fixed. `value1` (or `k` in my edited answer) is indeed pointless, but it's required by the method signature. `computeIfAbsent`'s second argument is a `Function<? super K,? extends V> mappingFunction` - a function that takes the key, and produces a new value based on it. The fact that this function always produces a new ArrayList regardless of what the key is is inconsequential